# Yarn package error after updating to node@16 using nvm

Tags: python, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to update the node version of my project to the latest version of node 16.
I have been using nvm to install and set node version.
My system is running on the following versions:

```
> node -v
v16.20.2

> npm -v
8.19.4

> python --version                                                                     
Python 3.11.7

> yarn -v
1.22.11
```

I keep run into this error trying to install packages using yarn.
I have tried to delete all modules and clear yarn cache and start over.
set path for python in .bash_profile & .zshrc.
Validate that path is correct.
Set python path for npm and yarn config.

Still no progression, nothing seems to work for me.
Need help from someone with similar issue.

Its an older project, used to run on node@12.
I have had other issues for other packages, that was resolved by updating the specific package.

```
error /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@16.20.2 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/local/bin/python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:402:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/node" "/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/core/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
```

Comment: That version of node-gyp requires python2 and you are getting that error because the build script is stil using python2 syntax but you are running it on python3  Maybe https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/docs/Updating-npm-bundled-node-gyp.md helps ?

Comment: Seems plausible, I will investigate!